# Making AWS RDS reachable from a Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, entity-framework, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I have a simple C# Lambda function that inserts a record into a table using Entity Framework. When I run the test locally (from my desktop machine) I can connect to the remote database just fine and the record gets inserted into the table at AWS just fine. When I upload the lambda to AWS and then send it data the function times out after 15 seconds. Since the code runs on my (external) desktop machine I am assuming that Lambda does not have permissions to connect to the internal RDS database from inside aws.

I have added AmazonRDSFullAccess to the permissions of the Lambda function. The Lambda function still times out.

What am I missing?

Comment: Your RDS is under VPC ?  If yes then you to have assign Lambda under same VPC and subnet group. Try one more thing is increasing timeout and memory.

Comment: See this that will help you... https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/connect-lambda-to-an-rds-instance/

Comment: @aviboy2006 it does not need to be in the same subnet as the RDS server.

Comment: one subnet group should from subnet of RDS

Comment: @aviboy2006 any subnet in the same VPC will work. Your subnet comments don't make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Lambda function needs to be deployed to the same VPC as the RDS server.

It does **not** need the `AmazonRDSFullAccess` IAM policy attached.

The security group for the RDS server needs to allow inbound connections from the security group assigned to the Lambda function.

Comment: This is one of thing need to check.